# When I insert data into a blob on my database extra data is loaded in

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle database that I a trying to upload blob data into using PHP, I have created a simple HTML form and PHP page for the upload. When I check the data in the table using DataGrip (Similar to SQLDeveloper) and download the picture that I uploaded it does not display on my Mac, and when I look at the picture in a hex editor it is completely different. What could be the cause of this?

```
<?php

    /*
        CREATE TABLE BLOBTABLE
        (
            identifier number,
            filename VARCHAR2(100),
            picture blob
        );

        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE InsertBlob(pID NUMBER, pName VARCHAR2, pPicture BLOB) AS
        begin
            INSERT INTO BlobTable (id, name, picture) VALUES (pID, pName, pPicture);
            exception
            when others then
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, sqlerrm);
        end;
    */
    define('DB_USER','AAA');
    define('DB_PSWD','KKK');
    define('DB_CONN_STR','QQQ');
    define('DB_CHARSET','AL32UTF8');

    $conn=oci_connect(DB_USER,DB_PSWD,DB_CONN_STR,DB_CHARSET);
    $stmt=oci_parse($conn,'BEGIN InsertBlob(:pIdentifier,:pFileName,:pContent); END;');
    // prepare variables
    $identifier  =111;
    $filename    =$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_filename=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    // bind primitive parameters
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':pIdentifier',$identifier);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':pFileName',$filename);
    // bind blob parameter
    $blob=oci_new_descriptor($conn,OCI_DTYPE_LOB);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':pContent',$blob,-1,OCI_B_BLOB);
    $bres=$blob->writetemporary(file_get_contents($tmp_filename));
    // execute statement and commit changes
    // specify OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT, otherwise you may get INVALID_OCI_HANDLE exception
    $res=oci_execute($stmt,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
    oci_commit($conn);
    // free resources and close connection
    $blob->free();
    if (!$res)
    {
        $e = oci_error($query);
        echo $e['message'];
    }
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I am using PHP 7 and running on RHEL 7, in AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the line assigning to $bres needed to be

```
$bres=$blob->writetemporary(file_get_contents($tmp_filename),OCI_TEMP_BLOB);
```